# need assistance with string object manipulation in javascript

Tags: javascript, object

I am receiving this form of an object from the form data

```
{
  no_of_sections: “2”,
  0: “10,20,20”,
  1: “10,10”
}
```

And I need to convert it to the following format

```
{
  no_of_sections: “2”,
  marks_per_main: “10,20,20|10,10”
}
```

The schema of the object remains the same.
for eg. if the `no_of_sections: "3"` then

```
{
  no_of_sections: “3”,
  0: “12,10,24”,
  1: “10,15”,
  2: "20,20,10,5"
}
```

The values for the comma separated values can be anything.

What is the most efficient way I can achieve this?

I do have lodash included if that helps.

Comment: Show us what you've tried.

Comment: can you rely on the scheme of the object? I meen can you be sure that if you have 3 sections the 3rd one would have the propertyname `2` and so on?

Comment: @Jeff yes, yes i can.

@RobertMoskal @nikhil
i have tried just the brute force way of iterating over it and just skipping the `no_of_sections` and then concatenating the rest with a `|`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function doit(obj) {
  var t = [];
  var retobj = {no_of_sections: obj.no_of_sections};
  for (var i=0; i < parseInt(obj.no_of_sections); i += 1) {
    t.push(obj[i]);
  }
  retobj.marks_per_main = t.join('|');
  return retobj;
}
```

I think that should do it - or to change object without creating a new one

```
function doit(obj) {
  var t = [];
  for (var i=0; i < parseInt(obj.no_of_sections); i += 1) {
    t.push(obj[i]);
    delete obj[i];
  }
  obj.marks_per_main = t.join('|');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var newObj = {}

newObj.no_of_sections = oldObj.no_of_sections
newObj.marks_per_main = oldObj[0] + '|' + oldObj[1]
```

If the 'oldObj' is always the same format, then this should do it.

Comment: but you would need to iterate trough the object as it could be 3 sections, or more

Comment: Sorry, i should have been more clear, it doesnt always have only 0 and 1
if the `no_of_sections` is `3` then it will have `0` `1` and `2` along with the `no_of_sections` properties

Answer (score 0):

based on MeltingPoint's answer:

```
var newObj = {}
var sections = [];

newObj.no_of_sections = oldObj.no_of_sections

for(i=0;i<parseInt(oldObj.no_of_sections);i++) {
   sections.push(oldObj[i]);
}
newObj.marks_per_main = sections.join('|');
```

Answer (score -1):

Please execute the code

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Demo</title>
<script>
    window.onload = function () {
        var jsonObj = {
            no_of_sections: "2",
            0: "10,20,20",
            1: "10,10"
        };
        document.getElementById("old").textContent = JSON.stringify(jsonObj);
        jsonObj.marks_per_main = jsonObj[0] + '|' + jsonObj[1];
        delete jsonObj[0];
        delete jsonObj[1];
        document.getElementById("new").textContent = JSON.stringify(jsonObj);
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<pre id="old"></pre>
<pre id="new"></pre>
</body>
</html>
```